# spec helper file not found, spec folder does not appear to be on default path

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I stupidly made some change to my project, where I installed some rails gems(my project is non rails) and now when I attempt to run my tests, rspec cannot find my spec_helper file even though it is contained in the spec folder.

Previously in my tests I had require 'spec_helper' at the top of each test spec file and they worked fine. Now after my change the spec helper cannot be found using this method. If I point my tests directly to the spec_helper file like this: 'require ../../spec_helper', they find the spec helper and the test will run. However this is not a good solution for me as I have tests in many different directories and sub directories so I would need to update all spec file with their respective correct paths.

According to this page: "https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/default-path" it would appear that the spec folder is no longer the default path and as such is not on the load path hence the spec helper file not been found.

Does anyone know how I can set the spec folder as the default path? This to the best of my knowledge is then added to the load path and then rspec can find the spec_helper file.

Any help would be great on this issue!

Thanks!

Rake file as requested:

```
require "rake"
require 'timeout'
require 'socket'

def ping addr
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
retval = false
begin
    retval = !Net::HTTP.get(URI(addr)).empty?
rescue
    retval = false
end
retval
end

task :default => [:runTest]

task :startServer do
if(not ping("http://localhost:4444"))
    puts "Starting server"
    SELENIUM_JAR = "../selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar"
    sh "java -jar #{SELENIUM_JAR} 2>&1 > /dev/null &"
    while not ping("http://localhost:4444")
        sleep 3
    end
else
    puts "Server already started"       
end
end

task :stopServer do
if(ping("http://localhost:4444"))
    puts "Shutting Down Server"
    sh "curl http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver             /?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer" 
else 
    puts "Server not started"   
end  
 end

task :runTest, [:cms_security, :ma] do|t, args|
if(not ping("http://test:4444"))
    puts "Server has not bee started"
    Rake::Task['startServer'].execute
end
sh "cucumber ./features"
puts "Done running tests"  
end
```

Comment: I don't know if it is right direction but: do you have a `Rakefile` in your app. if yes - post it.

Comment: sorry but I don't see Rakefile

Comment: sorry, couldnt not attach in a comment correctly. I added it to the end of the original question. Please note that I do not use rake to run my tests so not sure if this will be of much help!

Comment: well... It looks that I am wrong - it is wrong direction. PS I thought that maybe you should have similar settings as for minitest in gems...

Comment: yeah, no problems gotva. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: how are you running your spec?

Comment: I run my spec using by browsing to the features folder and running the command: rspec 'folder_name' My folder structure would be like this: spec > features > test folders. my spec_helper file lives in my spec folder.